# Resend data to socket endpoint if there's no response after a certain time

Tags: c#, sockets, task-parallel-library, async-await

I have the following TAP methods to read & write data to my sockets end points

```
    private async Task ReadFromAddress(string address)
    {
        IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(address), 4001);
        Socket client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                                   SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        sockets.Add(client);
        await client.ConnectTaskAsync(remoteEP);
        await ReadAsync(client);
    }

    private async Task ReadAsync(Socket s)
    {            
        var args = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
        args.SetBuffer(new byte[128], 0, 128);

        var awaitable = new SocketAwaitable(args);

        while (true)
        {
            await s.ReceiveAsync(awaitable);
            int bytesRead = args.BytesTransferred;
            if (bytesRead <= 0) break;

            var data = new ArraySegment<byte>(args.Buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            AppendLog("RX: " + data.DumpHex());
        }
    }


    public static Task<int> SendAsync(this Socket socket, byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        return Task.Factory.FromAsync<int>(
                       socket.BeginSend(buffer, offset, count, SocketFlags.None, null, socket),
                 socket.EndSend);            
    }
    public static Task<int> SendTaskAsync(this Socket socket, byte[] buffer, int offset, int size, SocketFlags flags)
    {
        AsyncCallback nullOp = (i) => { };
        IAsyncResult result = socket.BeginSend(buffer, offset, size, flags, nullOp, socket);
        // Use overload that takes an IAsyncResult directly
        return Task.Factory.FromAsync<int>(result, socket.EndSend);
    }
```

This is how I connect to my list of IP addresses

```
    private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var listOfIps = new List<string> { "192.168.168.199", "192.168.168.221" };

        await Task.WhenAll(listOfIps.Select(ip => ReadFromAddress(ip)));
    }
```

Each time I send some data using WriteAsync, I'm supposed to get some data back almost instantly. How should I extend my code, in a TAP-ified way if possible, such that if I don't get back any reply from that particular socket within say.. 3 seconds.. I will resend the data again?

This is how I write data to a particular socket:

```
var socket = sockets[i];
var returnMessage =new byte[2];
returnMessage[0] = 0x01;
returnMessage[1] = 0x02;
await socket.WriteAsync(returnMessage);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I recommend that you not mix different asynchronous systems. I recommend replacing `SocketAsyncEventArgs` with TAP methods.

To put in a timeout as you suggest, you'll want to create another layer. Your current code handles low-level reads and writes; you need a higher, message-level abstraction.

Comment: How would tie TAP versions of the SocketAsyncEventArgs be like? A code snippet would be helpful as to how I can do so in another layer

Comment: I meant use `FromAsync` wrappers consistently, just like you do for Connect.